# displaying codeigniter database error using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I get error 500 internal server error

I want to display database error to view, so far i can produce the response only in chrome network response

Model classes, I omit the constructor

```
class Size_mdl extends MY_Model {      
        public function create($data) {
           return $this->insert($data);  
        }
    }

class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
 public function insert($data) {
        $success = $this->db->insert($this->table_name, $data);
        if ($success) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $msg = $this->db->error();
            return $msg;
        }
    }
```

controller

```
$data['test_r'] = var_dump($this->Size_mdl->create($data));           
$this->load->view('size/create_size_view',$data);
```

View

This is Welcome.php, the most outer with header and footer

```
    <div class="page">
        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="page-head"></header>
         <!-- Page Content-->
        <main id="main_content" class="page-content"></main>
         <!-- Page Footer-->
         <footer class="page-foot section-60 section-xl-150 text-center text-lg-left">
```

Inside that page i have create_size_view loaded to main_content, previously it was homepage, bunch of stuff.

```
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <h5>Create New Size</h5>
            <div id="inner_container">
                <div id="create_part">
                    <?php
                    if (isset($test_r)){
                        echo $test_r;
                    }?>
                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <?php
                    $attributes = array('id' => 'create_size_form');
                    echo form_open("size/create", $attributes);
                    ?>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo lang('size_short_name_label', 'short_name'); ?>
                        <?php 
                            $short_name = array(
                                'name'          => 'short_name',
                                'id'            => 'short_name',
                                'maxlength'     => '100'
                            );
                            echo form_input($short_name);?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo lang('size_long_name_label', 'long_name'); ?>
                        <?php 
                            $long_name = array(
                                'name'          => 'long_name',
                                'id'            => 'long_name',
                                'maxlength'     => '100',
                            );
                            echo form_input($long_name);?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo form_submit('submit', lang('create_size_submit_btn')); ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('form#create_size_form').submit(function (e) {

            var form = $(this);

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('size/create'); ?>",
                data: form.serialize(), // <--- THIS IS THE CHANGE
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#main_content').html(result);
                },

            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Now i need the response for failed insert appear replacing main_content welcome.php or its children div from create_size_view.php. I can produce the successful insert by reloading create_size_view.php

Comment: Can you show your view with the div or span with the id of main_content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codeigniter predefined error handler for MySQL.
if error encountered  Codeigniter throw HTML content with 500 server site error
for avoiding this page 500 status code put Codeigniter ENVIRONMENT in production then your code will work properly.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. Is there any doc about this environment option? CI doc only show true/false

Comment: **change the Whole environment of CI**
index.php in root dir

change following

define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

to

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); //or development testing production

**OR OFF only debug of mysql**
/application/config/database.php
from :-
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
to :-
'db_debug' => false,

Answer (score 0):

change ajax url property. use url like "/size/create" dont use whith domain like "www.site.com/size/create";

Comment: Not working, 404 error. I have retrieved the correct response, it just wont appear on the page.

Comment: @andrewgiovanni dont need dataType remove 'dataType:"html"'

Answer (score 0):

use **text** for binding data

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('size/create'); ?>",
                data: form.serialize(), // <--- THIS IS THE CHANGE
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#main_content').text(result);
                }
            });
```